# remove NaN in my array display

Tags: javascript, arrays, nan

I want to ask help how to remove NaN value in my array. Every time I hit submit button without a data it will display a NaN value.

Variables for number sort :

```
var array = [];
var arrayasc = [];
var arraydsc = [];
function myFunction(){
    var newArray = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value);
    array.push(newArray);
    arrayasc.push(newArray);
    arraydsc.push(newArray);
    if
    //entered numbers dislay here
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = array;
    console.log(array);

    //entered numbers in ascending order
    mySort_asc(arrayasc);
    document.getElementById("asc").innerHTML = array;
    console.log(mySort_asc(arrayasc));

    //entered numbers in descending order
    mySort_dsc(arraydsc);
    document.getElementById("dsc").innerHTML = array;
    console.log(mySort_dsc(arraydsc));
}
```

Function to sort numbers in ascending order

```
function mySort_asc(arr){
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var temp = array[i];
        var b = i - 1;
        while (b >= 0 && array[b] > temp) {
          array[b + 1] = array[b];
          b--;
        }
        array[b + 1] = temp;
      }
      return array;
}
```

Function to sort numbers in descending order

```
function mySort_dsc(arr){
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var temp = array[i];
        var b = i - 1;
        while (b >= 0 && array[b] < temp) {
          array[b + 1] = array[b];
          b--;
        }
        array[b + 1] = temp ;
      }
      return array;
}
```

Comment: just check if an element has a value otherwise return empty string, best is to use ternary operator

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is invalid

```
if
//entered numbers dislay here
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = array;
```

but simply check to see if the new value is a number or not, and if it isn't, return immediately without changing anything in the HTML:

```
function myFunction(){
  var newArray = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value);
  if (Number.isNaN(newArray)) return;
```

You also might consider naming your variables to correspond to what they represent. For example, the `newArray` is actually just a single number, not an array. Perhaps call it `newValue`, for ease of reading and debugging?

Comment: thanks it really a great help, how about if its a string? how not to display the (,) comma?

Comment: You could use `replace` to replace all commas in the `newValue` with the empty string

Comment: I mean if the data is also empty the display is comma only how to catch it and not to display comma instead